# Pillow/PIL Python - only first row written to image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a Perlin noise application which generates a game map randomly. I am trying to write to a new image, however only the first row is being written.

Here is a stub I created which exhibits the same problem:

```
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

height = 25
width = 25

z = randint(-1000, 1000) / 100

img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=(255, 255, 255, 255))

for y in range(height):
    img.putdata([(0,255,0,255) for x in range(width)]) # Logic error occurs on this line
img.save("location.png", "PNG")
```

What stupid mistake am I making this time?

Comment: `Image.putdata()` wants the entire image's data in a single sequence; it doesn't support building an image in pieces.

Comment: You could replace `putdata` with `putpixel`, but this will probably be slow. If you're trying to set a region of the image to the same value, you could use the `ImageDraw` module's functions, e.g. `ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the pixel information in the following way:

```
img.putdata([(0,255,0, 255) for x in range(width) for y in range(height)])
```

The way you are providing the info, will create 25 sub-lists each of 25 elements whereas the function needs 625 elements without any sub-listing.

Comment: Thanks for this simple advice :D

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a sequence that fills up the whole image. `putdata` starts at 0,0 each time you call it, so you are just writing from 0,0 to the end of your sequence each time. Get a sequence that is long enough to fill the whole image by doing something like this:

```
height = 25
width = 25
data = [255 * randint(-1000, 1000) / 100 for x in range(width * height)]
```

Then you can use putdata like this:

```
img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=(255, 255, 255, 255))
img.putdata(data)
img.save("location.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response :D